# Showing check on checkbox if the value is checked

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

In the edit page, I wanted to have checked if the checkbox is true.

```
@foreach($benefits as $benefit)
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <label class="form-check-label" for="benefit[]">
                        @if ($edit)
                            <input class="form-check-input" @if($benefit->id == $user->benefit()->id) 'checked' @endif type="checkbox" value"{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]">
                        @else
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]">
                            {{$benefit->name}}
                          </label>
                        @endif
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Just like in the screenshot i attach. The "Eyewear","Dental", and "AVEGA" should be checked because theyre true in the database. Pls see pic for reference. 
[image]
Thanks experts

Comment: Help experts! Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I assume benefits is `hasMany` relationship with user in this case you need to compare like `in_array($benefit->id,  $user->benefit()->pluck('id'))` will return true or false

Comment: Theres an error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `benefits` inner join `users_benefits` on `benefits`.`id` = `users_benefits`.`benefit_id` where `users_benefits`.`user_id` = 16) (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php)

Comment: I think its the issue with how you have construct your relationship nothing to do with the code i advised you. Can you show me your benefits model from user model?

Comment: This is for the user


    public function benefits()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vanguard\Models\Benefits', 'users_benefits', 'user_id', 'benefit_id');
    }

Comment: The benefits i didnt put anything

Comment: try `in_array($benefit->id, $user->benefit()->pluck('id'))` to `in_array($benefit->id, $user->benefits->pluck('id'))` and see what happens

Comment: Theres an error saying in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php)

Comment: just add `->toArray()` at the end so your code should look like `$user->benefits->pluck('id')->toArray()` or just use collection method `$user->benefits->contains($benefit->id)`

Comment: <input class="form-check-input" if (in_array($benefit->id, $user->benefits->pluck('id')->toArray())) checked="checked" endif type="checkbox" value"{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]">
                            {{$benefit->name}}

Comment: Theres no checkbox checked and does not even show my benefits

Comment: You forget to add @ in front of both if and  end if

Comment: theres a "@" in my code, i just remove it here because they wont allow  it to comment

Comment: Try: `<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]" @if($benefit->id == $user->benefit()->id) checked @endif>`

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$id (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

remove single quote `'` in your code

```
   @if($benefit->id == $user->benefit()->id) checked @endif
```

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$id (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/user/partials/details.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="form-check-input" {{ ($benefit->id == $user->benefit->id ? 'checked': '') }} type="checkbox" value"{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]">
```

try this.

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I did and it work

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$benefit->id}}" id="benefit_id" name="benefit_id[]" @if($edit) @if($user->benefits->contains('id', $benefit->id)) checked @endif @endif>
```